# Bloc plugin issue using BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm new to `Flutter` and whole `Bloc` architecture so I'm following tutorial to understand it more, but it looks like `Bloc` was somehow redesigned because my version has completely different constructor.

Idk if its `Bloc` problem or I'm doing something wrong.

My BlocProvider:

```
BlocProvider<PlacesBloc> buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => sl<PlacesBloc>(),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Top view
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              PlacesControls(),
              // Bottom view
              BlocBuilder<PlacesBloc, PlacesState>(
                // ignore: missing_return
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is Empty) {
                    return MessageDisplay(
                      message: 'Search places around you!',
                    );
                  } else if (state is Loading) {
                    return LoadingWidget();
                  } else if (state is Loaded) {
                    return PlacesDisplay(places: state.places);
                  } else if (state is Error) {
                    return MessageDisplay(
                      message: state.message,
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`create` parameter does not exist in my version of Bloc.

Also inside my `Widget` I use `BlocProvider.of<PlacesBloc>(context).add(GetPlacesFromServer());` to add event to my 'BlocProvider' but this `.add` method does not exist in my Bloc.

Here is constructor differences between tutorial video(bottom) and mine (top):

[image]

Comment: Which exact package are you using? Name and version?

Comment: bloc by Felix Angelov, version 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tutorial was likely written for version 4.0.0 of the library, where it should work as you showed.

There were a lot of [breaking changes](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/changelog) in version 5.0.0 and 6.0.0.